# grunt syntax error issue on running grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
 grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    copy: {
        t1:{
          src: 'dir1/*',
          dest: 'dir2/'
          }
        }
 });
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy);
 grunt.registerTask('default', ["copy"]);
};
```

Trying grunt first time, could not find anywhere about issue, what is problem here, when i ran **grunt copy** it throws error.

> > Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
> >
> > SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> >
> > Warning: Task "copy" not found. Use --force to continue.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it's syntax error, my IDE not shown any error indications.

> grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

this is corrected.